# How to troubleshoot Karpenter using k9s?

Tags: kubernetes, debugging, karpenter

I have a kubernetes cluster with Karpenter installed in it. For some reasons, Karpenter doesn't launch the right nodes for my scheduled pods, and I want to troubleshoot it.

How to debug karpenter log and get karpenter configuration in my cluster using k9s?

My karpenter has 2 nodes, each with a controller and a webhook, but when I try to get their logs, k9s hangs with `Waiting for logs...`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what installation method you used. If you installed it from the below example https://ec2spotworkshops.com/karpenter/050_karpenter/install_karpenter.html it should work. Check if your role ARN is correct. Then just check it from CLI kubectl logs karpenter-pod-name -n karpenter